# "Can't connect to local MySQL Server" using SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, django, ssh, mysql-workbench, ssh-tunnel

Starting an SSH tunnel to MySQL so MySQL Workbench can connect to the remote DB using the following command:

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 <username>@<domain> -N
```

MySQL Workbench is able to connect without issue doing this.

I was also trying to spin up a local copy of the Django application and connect to the remote test DB and I get met with:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, 'Can\'t connect to local MySQL server through socket \'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock\' (2 "No such file or directory")'
```

Looking at the Django settings, everything looks correct. Just seems like Django is ignoring the tunnel despite using the same port. Django is in `virtualenv` so wonder if something there might be causing it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: workbench has the option to use ssh, only change the option standard tcp ip to the ssh. usually you have to enter credentials for ssh.

Comment: From the error message, it looks to me like the Django app is attempting to connect using a local unix socket, and not TCP/IP.  I think the "Django settings" for the database connection depend on which MySQL DB API being used,  mysqlcient or MySQL Connector/Python. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#mysql-notes   scroll down to "Connecting to the database".  Note that to MySQL, a hostname value of `localhost` does **not** mean IP loopback 127.0.0.1, it means use a local unix socket file. To force TCP/IP, we typically provide a port (3306) , and we can use an IP address.

Comment: As documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases     to connect to a local TCP/IP port, use HOST value of 127.0.0.1 , if HOST value starts with a forward slash, that is saying to use a local unix socket (that is, to not use TCP/IP). Without seeing the actual "Django settings", we're just guessing.

Comment: @spencer7593 So changing my DB host connection string to `127.0.0.1` from `localhost` resolved the issue. Thanks for the help! If you'd like to post the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the DB connection string in the `settings.py` to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.